# Change font size for PDF Text Annotation in Preview

Tags: pdf, preview

This should be dead simple: how to customize the font including face, style and modifications. But those configurations are nowhere to be seen.

[image]

So ... where is this hidden Preview/pdf toolbar / icon, whatever that allows setting the font ?

Here is what I see on the menu.

[image]

Right clicking on the textbox itself brings up the following - note that no way to change any text font/size. This is absurd.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Preview in Mavericks it is right below the main menu bar, where I can select the Font and the size.

[image: font]

Comment: did not notice that.

Answer (score 8):

In Yosemite, click the toolbox icon.  The tool bar will show all the editing and annotation tools.  One of them is the font configuration.
[image: Preview Toolbox]

Comment: It appears from your screen shot above that you are running Yosemite.  Glad @Buscar웃 's answer helped you.

Comment: Thank you for posting the Yosemite answer, you get a up vote from me for that.

Comment: Up vote to you as well for the Mavericks answer. :-) thanks @buscar