# Change font size for PDF Text comments in Preview

Tags: pdf, preview, font

I would like to change the font size for PDF Text *comments* in Preview? I am aware that acrobat allows you to do this. I am looking for 
a  solution in Preview (Version 8.1 (877.7))

This is a variation of [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/183306/24981), or that [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/284736/24981) which apply respectively to text font size or comments in MS Word.

Here I want to change the font in 
the **comments** of *Preview*.

Even if I copy a bigger text font inside it, it is made smaller once the note is closed. As this example shows, the comment font is too small for my eyes :-)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This might be relevant?
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070304081248710

**Attempt**

When I type

```
defaults read com.apple.Preview | grep PVAnnotationFontSize_5
```

I get

```
   "PVAnnotationFontSize_5" = 9;
```

So I tried

```
defaults write com.apple.Preview PVAnnotationFontSize_5 12
```

But it doe not seem to do the trick (even after login out and in again).

It did change the value though as can be seen via the Property list editor

[image: Mathematica graphics]

found in ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.plist as suggested by @ankiiiiiii

Comment: @ankiiiiiii this is unfortunate. I guess engineers/programmers at apple are all young with perfect eyesight ? :-)

Comment: `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.plist` has some annotation properties but I can't find size.

Comment: How do you get to Notes for preview? or do you mean the Annotations you add on a page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Download the tinker tool, then go to fonts and increase the size of the help tag and you're golden. The size of the notes in the preview will increase to 24. Relaunch preview to see the change. You can even delete the tinker tool after the setting is changed. The change in font size will remain. :) –

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `defaults write` in a slightly differently way with Preview and other sandboxed apps.

Using `defaults write com.apple.Preview ...` modifies (or creates) a plist file in ~/Library/Preferences.

As pointed out, that's not where Preview saves (or looks for) its preference file, which is in a nested subfolder of ~/Library/Containers instead.

To modify the correct plist, use: `defaults write -app Preview ...`

You'll need to make sure you have the correct key, too. I have the following keys in my Preview plist:

```
"PVAnnotationFontSize_12" = 10;
"PVAnnotationFontSize_17" = 10;
"PVAnnotationFontSize_5" = "11.99199";
"PVAnnotationFontSize_6" = 10;
```

However, modifying those does not change the text size for either Annotations or Notes. Annotations seem to keep the last settings used. Notes don't seem to be editable in the UI.

Also, note that you don't need to use grep to read a specific plist key. E.g. `defaults read com.apple.Preview PVAnnotationFontSize_5`

EDIT: Having probed into the plist data and the text strings within the Preview app itself, I'm not convinced that there is an editable key for the font size or style in Preview's Notes.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately it does not address my problem presently since I did not find which font to change.

Comment: Hey! Can you add in the answer the full address of the file? As I said, I dont even see the PVA... keys in the file at the path I wrote.

Comment: The path is <user>/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.plist. Changing the file in a text editor won't work, as the preferences are cached. Changing any of those keys doesn't seem to affect the text for Annotations or Notes. Annotations seems to remember the last font settings used. Notes don't.

Comment: @benwiggy I have these!  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf6vA.png

Answer (score 1):

[How can I change default font Notes - Sierra, High Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302763/how-can-i-change-default-font-notes-sierra-high-sierra#)
Is this relevant? I think the same could be done for Preview but I don't know how to figure out the hexadecimal code for the font and font size I want. 
I am struggling with the same problem and I really want a solution.

Comment: I figured it out. Download the tinker tool, then go to fonts and increase the size of the help tag and you're golden. The size of the notes in the preview will increase to 24. Relaunch preview to see the change. You can even delete the tinker tool after the setting is changed. The change in font size will remain.  :)

Comment: Thank you very much it did the trick!  Could pleas add this to your answer?